# What goes under the hood of `mkvirtualenv` command?

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am curious about what happens under the hood of the `mkvirtualenv` command and so I am trying to understand how it calls `virtualenv`.

The lowest hanging fruit is to figure where the virtualenv program is located after installation and where the mkvirtualenv program is located after installation. So:-

```
Calvins-MacBook-Pro.local ttys006 Mon Apr 23 12:31:07 |~|
calvin$ which mkvirtualenv
Calvins-MacBook-Pro.local ttys006 Mon Apr 23 12:31:10 |~|
calvin$ which virtualenv
/opt/local/library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv
```

So the strange thing I see here is that `which mkvirtualenv` does not give any result. Why?

Digging further, in the virtualenvwrapper directory after installing it, I see only 3 python files:-

```
Calvins-MacBook-Pro.local ttys004 Mon Apr 23 12:28:05 |/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper|
calvin$ ls -la
total 88
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel    272 Apr 13 15:07 .
drwxr-xr-x  29 root  wheel    986 Apr 15 00:55 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   5292 Apr 13 15:05 hook_loader.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   4810 Apr 13 15:07 hook_loader.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   1390 Apr 13 15:05 project.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   2615 Apr 13 15:07 project.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   7381 Apr 13 15:05 user_scripts.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  11472 Apr 13 15:07 user_scripts.pyc
```

And I suppose that the only reason why `mkvirtualenv` is now available in my terminal is because I have added in a `source/opt/local/library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`.  So answering the question I asked earlier, this is simply because `mkvirtualenv` is expressed as a bash function and is available in my terminal because I have sourced virtualenvwrapper.sh in my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files.

Digging into the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script, I see

```
# Create a new environment, in the WORKON_HOME.
#
# Usage: mkvirtualenv [options] ENVNAME
# (where the options are passed directly to virtualenv)
#
function mkvirtualenv {
    typeset -a in_args
    typeset -a out_args
    typeset -i i
    typeset tst
    typeset a
    typeset envname
    typeset requirements
    typeset packages

    in_args=( "$@" )

    if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]
    then
        i=1
        tst="-le"
    else
        i=0
        tst="-lt"
    fi
    while [ $i $tst $# ]
    do
        a="${in_args[$i]}"
        # echo "arg $i : $a"
        case "$a" in
            -a)
                i=$(( $i + 1 ));
                project="${in_args[$i]}";;
            -h)
                mkvirtualenv_help;
                return;;
            -i)
                i=$(( $i + 1 ));
                packages="$packages ${in_args[$i]}";;
            -r)
                i=$(( $i + 1 ));
                requirements="${in_args[$i]}";;
            *)
                if [ ${#out_args} -gt 0 ]
                then
                    out_args=( "${out_args[@]-}" "$a" )
                else
                    out_args=( "$a" )
                fi;;
        esac
        i=$(( $i + 1 ))
    done

    set -- "${out_args[@]}"

    eval "envname=\$$#"
    virtualenvwrapper_verify_workon_home || return 1
    virtualenvwrapper_verify_virtualenv || return 1
    (
        [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT
        \cd "$WORKON_HOME" &&
        "$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV" $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS "$@" &&
        [ -d "$WORKON_HOME/$envname" ] && \
            virtualenvwrapper_run_hook "pre_mkvirtualenv" "$envname"
    )
    typeset RC=$?
    [ $RC -ne 0 ] && return $RC

    # If they passed a help option or got an error from virtualenv,
    # the environment won't exist.  Use that to tell whether
    # we should switch to the environment and run the hook.
    [ ! -d "$WORKON_HOME/$envname" ] && return 0

    # If they gave us a project directory, set it up now
    # so the activate hooks can find it.
    if [ ! -z "$project" ]
    then
        setvirtualenvproject "$WORKON_HOME/$envname" "$project"
    fi

    # Now activate the new environment
    workon "$envname"

    if [ ! -z "$requirements" ]
    then
        pip install -r "$requirements"
    fi

    for a in $packages
    do
        pip install $a
    done

    virtualenvwrapper_run_hook "post_mkvirtualenv"
}
```

Here's where I don't understand yet - I don't seem to see any direct reference to `virtualenv` in this bash function.  So how exactly does this bash function `mkvirtualenv` pass the arguments from command line (e.g. `mkvirtualenv -p python2.7 --no-site-packages mynewproject`) to the python `virtualenv` program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is the line that does the trick.

```
(
    [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT
    \cd "$WORKON_HOME" &&
    "$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV" $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS "$@" &&
    [ -d "$WORKON_HOME/$envname" ] && \
        virtualenvwrapper_run_hook "pre_mkvirtualenv" "$envname"
)
```

`$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV` is in fact the location of where the current `virtualenv` program resides.

In terminal,

```
Calvins-MacBook-Pro.local ttys004 Mon Apr 23 13:24:14 |~|
calvin$ which $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV
/opt/local/library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv
```

Mytsery solved.